# Ways to quickly input a filename into a command shell command

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, shell

I need to input filenames into command prompt for commands. To date I either manually type the filenames or copy and paste by calling up the file's properties tab and copying the full name.

Here's a generic example:

```
move file_name_1.txt whatever_name_i_want.txt
```

So I need a method of quickly inputting this "`file_name_1.text`"

What are some other methods that could be used? I can use `forfiles` to display all the files in the folder, isn't there some kind of number calling I can substitute for the file I want or something short and easy. Like ideally a dnd, would require some other shell type which is fine, or some callup command I could use that could tie into things.

Comment: Usually, tab completion helps.  If there is a file called  `file_name_1.txt` and you want to enter `move file_name_1.txt`, try typing `move fil[tab]`.

Comment: Alternatively, consider use a command-line-friendly file manager like [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander).  On a debian or Ubuntu-like system, install it  via `apt-get install mc`.

Comment: It doesn't recognize move fil[tab], and im using the exact same filenames. move file_name_1.txt works fine. I don't know how to build Midnight Commander, and the windows binary is pretty sketchy looking. Is there a layman's guide to building such things?

Comment: I opened a new question for the installation of MC: https://superuser.com/questions/1420164/how-to-build-midnight-commander-on-windows-8-1

Comment: I don't use Windows so I can't help with that.  If mc is not readily available, there are probably some similar programs that are.  Separately, if you want to become a command-line power user, as your question suggests, you might look at Ubuntu-for-Windows.  Good luck.

Comment: Hmm.  I see from your other question that you are using Win8.  I believe that Ubuntu-for-Windows requires Win10 so that's not a fit.